# MySQL with Kubernetes Persistent Volume Access Modes (GKE)

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a 3 node cluster. What I am going to do is create a persistence volume with **ReadWriteMany** access mode for MySQL Deployment. Also, Mount Option is GCEPersistentDisk.
My question is if I could use ReadWriteMany access mode for MySQL deployment, Will it be an issue? Because the volume can be mounted by many nodes. if I am wrong please correct me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can be an issue when the backend doesn't support ReadWriteMany, however, as per my knowledge MySQL supports ReadWriteMany. So it should not be an issue in your case.

Comment: Thank you. But If pods of three nodes trying to connect to persistence dist simultaneously, will it be any issue?

Comment: That should be already handled in MySQL code, you need not worry about it.

Comment: Can you explain the Access Mode of Persistence Volume (RWO, RWX)?. I didn't get an idea from the doc. because no explainable details were added?

Answer (score 1):

GCE persistent disks do not support ReadWriteMany. You can see this here in the documentation:   `
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/persistent-volumes#access_modes

However, there is a workaround to achieve the same with a NFS server:
https://medium.com/@Sushil_Kumar/readwritemany-persistent-volumes-in-google-kubernetes-engine-a0b93e203180

I wouldn't recommend this as the MySQL performance will be suboptimal, though. Consider using a [Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql) instance instead, and connecting from multiple nodes nodes to that using MySQL protocol instead of accessing the disk.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you give some idea of the Access Mode of Persistence Volume (RWO, RWX)?. I didn't get an idea from the doc?

Comment: See a very detailed breakdown in the Kubernetes documentation: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes

Comment: I already read it. It doesn't detailed. The question is when we are using persistence volume like google persistence volume it only supports RWO. Like this situation how can we scale pods with other nodes? Does that mean we have to use node affinity? am I write?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve; Why exactly do you need to write to a single disk from multiple nodes? This is possible in different ways using a variety of different software; MySQL (for structured data), MongoDB (key-pair), Google Cloud Storage or NFS (accessing files remotely), or even Rook (https://rook.io/) or GlusterFS (https://www.gluster.org/) all of these can be deployed on GKE and they will allow you to share data between instances without having to rely on ReadWriteMany, which has issues of multiple instances writing the same file at the same time (race condition)